# how to split echo from php in 2 different divs with jquery ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to split the echo which comes from php in 2 different divs in my ajax success.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'counter.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
               some_data:some_data                             
               },                   
        success: function(data){
            $('.div1').html(data); // in here 1st echo
            $('.div2').html(data); // in here 2nd echo
        },

    });
```

Piece of code from counter.php looks like this:

```
if (file_exists($blogfile)) {
   echo 'content updated'; // this echo should come in div1
}
else {
   echo 'file does not exist anymore'; // this echo should come in div2
}
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can simple return true or false then write an `IF` check an base of that write in one of the two `div`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to return a JSON object from your PHP, which contains two properties: firstly - the message itself, secondly - some sort of status indicator which the JS can use to decide what to do with the message.

e.g.

PHP:

```
$result = array();

if (file_exists($blogfile)) {
   $result["message"] = 'content updated'; // this echo should come in div1
   $result["status"] = 1;
}
else {
   $result["message"] = 'file does not exist anymore'; // this echo should come in div2
   $result["status"] = 2;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'counter.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { 
    some_data:some_data                             
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    var div;
    if (data.status == 1) div = $('.div1');
    else div = $('.div2');
    div.html(data.message);
  },
});
```